# cannot override flask_bootstrap css

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2, flask-bootstrap

I am trying to add static css files to my flask application. I am using flask_bootstrap and I cannot manage to implement it correctly - I believe I followed the documentation at

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html

but something is wrong. Here are the files in question.

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import os
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app,db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
mail = Mail(app)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)


if not app.debug:
    if app.config['MAIL_SERVER']:
        auth = None
        if app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] or app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']:
            auth = (app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'], app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'])
        secure = None
        if app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']:
            secure = ()
        mail_handler = SMTPHandler(
            mailhost=(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'], app.config['MAIL_PORT']),
            fromaddr='no-reply@' + app.config['MAIL_SERVER'],
            toaddrs=app.config['ADMINS'], subject='WebApp Failure',
            credentials=auth, secure=secure)
        mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)

    if not os.path.exists('logs'):
        os.mkdir('logs')
    file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/webapp.log', maxBytes=10240,
                                    backupCount=10)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.info('webapp startup')


from app import routes, models, errors
```

base.html

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    {% if title %}{{ title }} - LAMD{% else %}Welcome to LAMD{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="url_for('.static',filename='style.css')">
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. Turns out that in the href attribute of the link tag, I omitted the double braces containing the url_for function.